# When and best method of authenticating a RESTful API

Tags: rest, api, restful-authentication

I am currently building a restful API for a project, I have read up alot of standards followed for JSON backed RESTful API, what I am wondering is when/how I should authenticate certain calls.

When retrieving a singular user, would an 'idtoken' (I use google auth and use idtokens to verify any action made) should be used in the GET, because I want the API usage in the future but also want to protect the current users.

currently all my API are used with 'POST', and then read like

> {action: 'get', idtoken: '213125325vmeis134bo234' }

and the query, once the data is verified will be returned.

I am not sure if I should just have a GET request for this instead, and if so should I remove authentication on it, or just modify what is received by the client?

Apart from this I grasp most of the other aspects of the API, I was just wondering how more robust business APIs manage these sorts of things.

**Note** Currently I verify every request made with the ID token, even just standard GETs, I feel this isnt the way to use RESTful properly and want to ensure good programming practices

Comment: Missing info about environment in which you are working. In Asp.net Core is the most common authentication (and built-in) mechanism using of JWT token.
https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

Comment: Obligatory comment: it's not really a restful API if you use POST for everything and you put actions in request bodies. This is an RPC API and that's ok! A better question to ask is: what is a good way to authenticate a HTTP api because that can encompass both RPC and REST. The answer to that is probably at least: use a HTTP Authorization header instead of embedding secrets into a body.

Comment: The common practice is to use the Authorization header:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate the insight and now use and understand the jwt token authentication flow passing it in the auth header as a bearer token